# ftp access to prestashop database

Tags: sql, ftp, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I would like to mass edit "quantity" and "enabled" product attributes of a SQL (Prestashop) database from my home PC running Windows Vista.  The website designer has set up a private FTP account which gives direct access to the root folder of the shop and the appropriate passwords.
What software tools do I need to create the FTP connection and edit the SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to the SQL database using FTP, as it is for files upload, not for databases.

You need to ask your website qualified person to give you the `phpMyAdmin` login - a tool to edit databases. But as you are new to it - better do not touch!

You can mass edit an attribute `enabled` in your Prestashop backoffice product list.